# How to replace all characters in a string with '*' in perl

Tags: perl5.8

How to get a regular expression to replace all characters in a string in perl with *? The string has some utf-8 or iso-8859-1 characters also. I tried with "s/\w/*/g". But it did not replace utf-8 or iso-8859-1 characters.

```
my $value="hellö";
print "$value\n";
$value =~ s/\w/*/g;
print "after replacing $value\n"; //It prints ****ö.
```

I expect all characters should be replaced with * i.e hellö should be replaced with *****.

Please note, few special characters like -,_,\,/ etc should be skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to skip just a few characters, you can always do something along the lines of

```
 s/[^, \/\\\-]/*/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace *all* the characters in a string?  The `\w` is for matching word characters, but using just a dot should match all characters:  `s/./*/g`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any option to skip few special characters on that string which should not be replaced? Like '17/03/2019' to **/**/****.

Comment: Sure, but it gets a bit more tricky once you get into more than "replace all".  If you want to match just digits, then `s/[0-9]/*/g` would do the trick.

Comment: The string may contains any iso-8859-1 characters. Out of all characters few special characters like comma(,), space( ), slashes(\/) and hypen(-) should be skipped.

Comment: What's the common theme among the characters which should not be matched?  I have very limited experience with non-US English characters sets, but perl supports all kinds of matches on things like punctuation, or language-specific properties.  Ref: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html

Comment: Thanks, this document would help me a lot.